# C++(or Visual Studio) saving the file will not preserve the original file contents

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio

I'm new to server-side development, but I know a lot of things from front-end development

My problem:

1. From the client side (React.js application), a JSON string is sent (POST request) to a C++ server:

```
  const handleFetchData = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(setRepoUrl(inputUrl))
      const urlParts = inputUrl.split('/')
      const username = urlParts[3]
      const repo = urlParts[4]
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repo}/issues`
      )
      dispatch(setIssues(response.data))

      const api_data = JSON.stringify(response.data)

      await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5174/user_data.json', { api_data })
      console.log('Data saved on server:', api_data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
    }
  }
```

2. The C++ server processes this request and writes it to a file, but first deletes existing data in the .json file:

```
    void TcpServer::writeData(const std::string& data)
    {
        remove(user_data_path);
        size_t start = data.find("{");
        if (start == std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cerr << "JSON data not found in the input string.\n\n" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::string jsonData = data.substr(start);

        std::ofstream file(user_data_path, std::ios::out);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            file << jsonData << std::endl;
            file.close();
            std::cout << "Data saved to user_data.json\n\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open file for writing.\n\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

3. After writing the JSON string to the .json file, the Visual Studio application displays a window with the following error message:
File Load
Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file
Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents
[image]

4. After that, some characters in the JSON string are transformed into this - (\r\n\t\t<Ex1 innerRef={ref}>\r\n\t\t\t{children}\r\n\t\t</Ex1>\r\n\t);\r\n});���������������������������������7#�

Perhaps someone knows what the problem is and how to fix it.
In the end, I need a valid JSON string.

P.S. This server is written for Windows (#include <winsock.h>).
I don't want to provoke dissatisfaction in the comments like "why is he writing a server in C++ instead of node.js, etc."
I am a Junior Front-end Developer, and I just like C++, so I chose this language.
Thank you for understanding, I hope for your help.

I've been searching for a solution to the problem for a long time and simply came to the conclusion to write a post on Stack Overflow, so I don't have any versions of the solution to this problem.

Comment: There is no issue with the C++ code you posted -- it gets a string, opens a file, writes the string to a file.  What that string contains -- that is a different story.  What you need to do is use a debugger and see exactly what `data` contains when you call `writeData`.  Having to see what Visual Studio does is too late in the game.  My crystal ball is telling me you created the `std::string` of `data` without using the actual length of the data, i.e. `std::string data = <whatever>;` instead of `std::string data(whatever, length_of_whatever);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the buffer size which was 30720 bytes.

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 500000000;
```

I just changed the size which is approximately 500MB and now select them from the heap.

```
char* buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

This is where the buffer is used, I simply take data from it and then pass it as an argument to a function that writes this data to a file:

```
void TcpServer::startListen()
{
   if (listen(m_socket, 20) < 0)
   {
       exitWithError("Socket listen failed");
   }

   std::ostringstream ss;
   ss << "\n*** Listening on ADDRESS: " << inet_ntoa(m_socketAddress.sin_addr) << " PORT: " << ntohs(m_socketAddress.sin_port) << " ***\n\n";
   log(ss.str());

   int bytesReceived;

   while (true)
   {
       log("====== Waiting for a new connection ======\n\n\n");
       acceptConnection(m_new_socket);

       char* buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

       bytesReceived = recv(m_new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
       if (bytesReceived < 0)
       {
           exitWithError("Failed to receive bytes from client socket connection");
       }

       std::ostringstream ss;
       ss << "------ Received Request from client ------\n\n";
       log(ss.str());

       sendResponse();

       std::string requestData(buffer);
       handleRequest(requestData);

       delete[] buffer;
       closesocket(m_new_socket);
   }
```

}

The data was written to the file as needed because the buffer size could not accommodate large data.